# Numpy: vectorization for multiple values

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Imagine you have an RGB image and want to process every pixel:

```
import numpy as np
image = np.zeros((1024, 1024, 3))

def rgb_to_something(rgb):
    pass

vfunc = np.vectorize(rgb_to_something)
vfunc(image)
```

`vfunc` should now get every RGB value. The problem is that numpy flattens the
array and the function gets `r0, g0, b0, r1, g1, b1, ...` when it should get
`rgb0, rgb1, rgb2, ...`.
Can this be done somehow?

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Maybe by converting the numpy array to some special datatype beforehand?

For example (of course not working):

```
image = image.astype(np.float32)
import ctypes
RGB = ctypes.c_float * 3
image.astype(RGB)
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Update:
The main purpose is efficiency here. A non vectorized version could simply look like this:

```
import numpy as np
image = np.zeros((1024, 1024, 3))
shape = image.shape[0:2]
image = image.reshape((-1, 3))
def rgb_to_something((r, g, b)):
    return r + g + b
transformed_image = np.array([rgb_to_something(rgb) for rgb in image]).reshape(shape)
```

Comment: Can you separate the 3d array into 3 separate 1d arrays (1 for each channel) and use that as the arguments for your vectorized function?

Comment: Yes works! But I'll have to profile how efficient that is.

Comment: Array seperation is a good deal faster than the loop but larsmans solution still beats it (I got 2.7s, 0.8s and 0.3s with a simple test). But it is still interesting if you want to use an existing function (e.g. from the colorsys module).

Comment: I think you need [`np.apply_over_axes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html)

Comment: or [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way to solve this kind of problem is to pass the entire array to the function and used vectorized idioms inside it. Specifically, your `rgb_to_something` can also be written

```
def rgb_to_something(pixels):
    return pixels.sum(axis=1)
```

which is about 15 times faster than your version:

```
In [16]: %timeit np.array([old_rgb_to_something(rgb) for rgb in image]).reshape(shape)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.03 s per loop

In [19]: %timeit image.sum(axis=1).reshape(shape)
1 loops, best of 3: 192 ms per loop
```

The problem with `np.vectorize` is that it necessarily incurs a lot of Python function call overhead when applied to large arrays.

Comment: Ok, that was just an example. What about more complex operations that are not built into numpy? (pure python please, writing C extensions is fine but tedious if you just want to try something) Particulary how do you deal with arrays of vectors (rgb, velocity, ...).

Comment: Generalizing from my example, you'd use expressions that vectorize along the y axis, i.e. that deal with large numbers of short vectors in one go. If you want to compute `f(a,b)` for a large number of `a,b` pairs, then you'd implement a function that takes a pair of equally large arrays.

Comment: "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop." http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: @endolith: yep. And I can tell from experience that calling a Python function in a loop in a C extension to fill an array doesn't improve performance much either, so `np.vectorize` actually can't do much better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Numexpr](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) for some cases. For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr
rgb = np.random.rand(3,1000,1000)
r,g,b = rgb
```

In this case, numexpr is 5x faster than even a "vectorized" numpy expression. But, not all functions can be written this way.

```
%timeit r*2+g*3/b
10 loops, best of 3: 20.8 ms per loop

%timeit numexpr.evaluate("(r*2+g*3) / b")
100 loops, best of 3: 4.2 ms per loop
```